# Salesforce can't setDeviceToken on new SFMCSdk

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, push-notification

I migrated to SPM with MarketingCloudSDK 8.0.3 and SFMCSDK 1.0.2. I got `Missing or invalid Device Token` with status `Not Opted In`. After debugging, I got a problem when doing setDeviceToken.

Below is what I did.

```
func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data
    ) {
        SFMCSdk.mp.setDeviceToken(deviceToken)
        print(SFMCSdk.mp.deviceToken() ?? "error: no token - was UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications() called?")
    }
```

The deviceToken (Data) is there. However, the SFMCSdk.mp.deviceToken() (String) is nil, and error message is printed out. Please help to point me what I did wrongly.

P/s: The old version is working fine, `MarketingCloudSDK.sharedInstance().sfmc_deviceToken()` returns a string value.

```
func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data
    ) {        
        MarketingCloudSDK.sharedInstance()
            .sfmc_setDeviceToken(deviceToken)
        print(MarketingCloudSDK.sharedInstance().sfmc_deviceToken() ?? "error: no token - was UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications() called?")
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to make sure you are registering for remote notifications AFTER the SDK is initialized. Setting up registration should be done in the completion handler of Apple's  `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization`, which would be done inside the completion of the SFMCSdk's func `setPush(config: ModuleConfig, onCompletion: ((OperationResult) -> Void)? = nil) -> ConfigBuilder`

Comment: Hi, I tried to put `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization` inside`setPush(config: ModuleConfig, onCompletion: ((OperationResult) -> Void)? = nil) -> ConfigBuilder` success completion, but the SFMCSdk.mp.deviceToken() still return nil. What I don't clear is MarketingCloudSDK.sharedInstance().sfmc_deviceToken() is not nil but SFMCSdk.mp.deviceToken() is nil

Comment: Thanks Skyler Tanner, it works when I call `registerForRemoteNotifications()` after setPush completion success. `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` in AppDelegate is triggered and `SFMCSdk.mp.deviceToken()` has data as expected.